# Criteria used to determine if a "Chinese inch" is an "inch"?

Tags: nouns, terminology, language-evolution, construction

This is a follow-on question to "[Term for construct in which adjective completely changes the meaning of its following noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170093/term-for-construct-in-which-adjective-completely-changes-the-meaning-of-its-foll)"

Is a "Chinese inch" an "inch" or something entirely different in which the only correct term is the compound "Chinese inch"?

The English language word "inch" has been intended to indicate a specific length with a significant degree of rigor, even though both the definition and determination of precision has been refined over time.

"Chinese inch" is a term for a unit that is similar in magnitude but is significantly different from an "inch" in actual length (apparently, 1 inch = 0.762 Chinese inches; authority of definition not determined; appears to have multiple, inconsistent definitions.)

So, is a "Chinese inch" a type of "inch"?  It has a degree of transparency: both are units of length of similar magnitude.  It could also be considered completely opaque: use of "inch" instead of "Chinese inch" could result in the embarrassing fit of clothing, the disastrous misdirection of a Mars-bound spacecraft, or tragic surgical results.

I can't determine if the compound "Chinese inch" is endocentric in that the sense of "unit of length" is preserved, or if it is exocentric since the length is indeed appreciably different in the same manner that a "kilometer" differs from a "mile."

Has there been a semantic change, so that "inch" is now a class of length units instead of a specific unit of length?  To be specific, must one now use "English inch" or "American inch"?

Is it correct to advertise a tape measure using the "inch scale" if the scale is really in "Chinese inches"?

Comment: Here is my proposed answer to following question: what criteria is used to determine if a "Chinese inch" is an "inch"?    

1.) The unmodified term "inch" means 2.54 centimeters.  A modifier is required only if the length unit in question is not 2.54 centimeters or if confusion could result.      

2) The term "inch" can also refer to the class of length measurements "inches"; this can be determined by a modifier to the term "inch" or by the context.      

3) The term "Chinese inch" is in the class of "inches" but is not an "inch" in any other sense.

Answer (score 3):

A *Chinese inch* is simply a [unit of measurement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_units_of_measurement). It has no relationship to the inch, it's just called that way in English. No, *inches* are not a class of unit, an inch is an inch but a *Chinese inch* is something different.

There are many examples of such qualified names for units of measurement. For instance, the [American pint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pint_glass) is 473 ml while the British pint is 568 ml. A *billion* means 10<sup>9</sup> in the US but 10<sup>12</sup> in the UK. It's not that they're both members of the class *millions*, or *pints*, they simply mean different things in the different dialects.

The Chinese inch is the name adopted in the English language for the Chinese cùn. It is not one of many inches, it is *the Chinese inch*. So no, no semantic change has occurred, the Chinese inch is to an inch as a kilometer is to a mile.

Comment: Some people might assume "chinese inch" is a derogatory term for a smaller/lower quality inch. In the same way as a hammer is a Birmingham Screwdriver

Comment: Actually, I believe the UK has largely given in on alternate notion of a billion; certainly *The Economist* has, per their style guide.

Comment: I wish English speakers would feel freer to adopt elements from languages other than Latin and Greek.  I would rather adopt the word "cùn" from Chinese instead of overloading "inch".  I've searched multiple dictionaries; the current prevailing definition of "inch" always seems to be defined in terms that point to a single, precise length measurement, even though -- as noted below by oerkelens -- _inch_ was never a fixed length.

I've become swayed against overloading after having used computer languages that become degraded as semantic elements are added by overloading existing constructs.

Comment: The Chinese inch is to the English inch as the French inch is to the inch. There's a reason it was analogized to the inch by the English instead of treated as a *sui generis* foreign unit like the stade: They absolutely *did* consider it an informal category of units of measurement, into which the 寸 neatly fell. There isn't any international scientific body that ever delineated a formal schema for the boundaries between inch units, foot units, and the rest but such analogizing and categorizing is where the name came from.

Comment: @lly I am afraid I don't understand what you are trying to say at all. There is no such thing as a "French inch", nor is there any general category of units called "inches". _Inch_ is just the term used for a small unit of length in the English language so, by extension, it was used to describe other, unrelated small units of length like the cùn.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't determine if the compound "Chinese inch" is endocentric in that the sense of "unit of length" is preserved, or if it is exocentric since the length is indeed appreciably different in the same manner that a "kilometer" differs from a "mile."

I would say it is definitely endocentric, as the compound still has "inch" as its head. The meaning of "measure of length" is not essentially changed, as is the case with fluid ounce and light year.

*Inch* was never by any standard a *fixed* length, even though we tend to see it that way nowadays. The inch is traditionally equivalent to the thumb (Dutch duim, French pouce), even today in French, an inch is called a thumb (pouce). Just like the yard, which seems linked to the old ell or cubit (Dutch el, all related to the length of the arm between elbow and the top of one of the fingers), or the foot, it had a common definition, but since humans are all built differently, its actual size would basically depend on the person measuring.

Standardization set in at some point, but even then, there have been (and in some cases there still are) different standards between countries or even inside countries.

In that perspective, it is not strange to see "Chinese inch" as just another standard length, in this case a Chinese standard, just like the similar compounds imperial pint or nautical mile.

As for your concerns about the risks of mixing up or misinterpreting different standards of measurements, those concerns are valid, and have existed throughout human history. That is the reason that for as long as we can trace back, people have tried to standardize measures, whether they were measuring amounts of grain, distances or weight of gold. And after thousands of years of these efforts, we have still not managed to truly implement one working standard, as is illustrated by the crashing Mars probe - and even closer to home, people in "metric" countries still buying and selling pints of beer and pounds of meat without seeming very concerned about any official and strict definitions of those measures (for most, half a litre and half a kilo for the pint and pound respectively are good enough).

Comment: I beg to disagree with your last parenthesis. "A ’alf litre ain’t enough. It don’t satisfy. And a ’ole litre’s too much. It starts my bladder running. Let alone the price." (*1984*, ch.8)

Comment: @TimLymington Depends which side of the pond you're on: a [pint](https://www.google.com/search?q=%3D+473.176473+milliliters&oq=pint&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3568j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) can well be less than half a litre, and good luck pickin' a figh over that over on the other side :)

Comment: Overall correct, although it would benefit from toning down a few of the absolutes. The inch was standardized as early as some of the earliest surviving laws of England, Scotland, and Wales: the issue was always about enforcement of the standards & the interest of tradesmen in getting more coin for less material. This repeatedly led to different standards in different markets & in different products within the same market, although more often in weights and in the longer lengths used for cloth than in the inch itself.

Answer (score -1):

[*meta*: Essentially an overlong comment]

> [Definition: Chinese inch](http://www.convertunits.com/from/inches/to/chinese+inch) The cun (Chinese: 寸; pinyin: cùn; Wade-Giles: ts'un) is a traditional Chinese unit of length. Its traditional measure is the width of a person's thumb at the knuckle, whereas the width of the two forefingers denotes 1.5 cun and the width of all fingers side-by-side is three cuns. In this sense it continues to be used to chart acupuncture points on the human body in various uses of traditional Chinese medicine.
>   
>   The cun was part of a larger system, and represented one-tenth of a chi (Chinese foot). In time the lengths were standardized, and in Hong Kong, using the traditional standard, it measures ~3.715 cm (~1.463 in). In the twentieth century in the Republic of China, the lengths were standardized to fit with the metric system, and in current usage in China and Taiwan it measures 31⁄3 cm (~1.312 in).

ExecSum: The *Chinese* in *Chinese inch* is a simple adjective to the broader term *[inch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inch)* and not a name, the Chinese call it the *[Cun](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Chinese+inch)*.

Comment: I'm going to start using the word "cun".  The entire subject of "Chinese inches" came up after I purchased tape measures online that were advertised to measure the "inch" scale.  I had them sent to some of my family -- now I've asked my family to discard them to avoid confusion.  However, initially, I was pleased that my waist was slimmer and my weight loss program seemed to be working well.

Comment: (a) Cun isn't cùn, (b) 寸 is only cùn in Mandarin, (c) the Chinese call it a 寸 in Chinese, not in English, and (d) 寸 in Chinese is precisely **and more often** the translation of English "inch" in ideas like pizzas and television sizes. It's sometimes distinguished as the English inch (英寸) on for example very strict tests but not in general culture, where translations of the English "inch" is the only common use for 寸 outside of proverbs. That said your source is wrong and the traditional definition relates to the distance between the wrist and the location nearby where pulses are taken.